# Referencing activity in a fragment using a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

This is my first time trying to implement a `ViewPager`.  My app basically has a listing and details page and I'd like the user to be able to swipe between the details.  The details are based on an id that I pass in from the listing page.  The problem is that I'm calling `getActivity()` in the details fragment, which is coming back null.  Like I said, I'm new to implementing a `ViewPager` so this might be something obvious:

ListingFragment.class:

```
public class ListingFragment extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
    private ViewPager mViewPager;  
    private MyFragmentPagerAdapter mMyFragmentPagerAdapter; 
    private static List<Fragment> fragments;
    public int Id = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle)
    {    
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);  
        mMyFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());  
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mMyFragmentPagerAdapter);

        DetailsFragment df1 = new DetailsFragment();
        df1.Id = 1;
        df1.DisplayItems();
        fragments.add(lf);

        DetailsFragment df2 = new DetailsFragment();
        df2.Id = 2;
        df2.DisplayItems();
        fragments.add(lf);
    }

    private static class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {  

        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {  
             super(fm);  
        }  

        @Override  
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {  
            return fragments.get(index);
        }  

        @Override  
        public int getCount() {  
             return 2;  
        }  
   }
}
```

DetailsFragment.class

```
public class DetailsFragment extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle icicle)
    {    
        super.onActivityCreated(icicle);
    }

    private void DisplayItems()
    {
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).getBoolean("value", false);
        ...
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've updated my code to use static `newInstance` method and a `Bundle` to pass the id to the details fragment.

ListingFragment.class:

```
public class ListingFragment extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
    private ViewPager mViewPager;  
    private MyFragmentPagerAdapter mMyFragmentPagerAdapter; 
    private static List<Fragment> fragments;
    public int Id = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle)
    {    
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);  
        mMyFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());  
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mMyFragmentPagerAdapter);

        DetailsFragment df1 =  DetailsFragment.newInstance(1);
        fragments.add(df1);

        DetailsFragment df2 =  DetailsFragment.newInstance(2);
        fragments.add(df2);
    }

    private static class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {  

        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {  
             super(fm);  
        }  

        @Override  
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {  

            return fragments.get(index);
        }  

        @Override  
        public int getCount() {  
             return 2;  
        }  
   }
}
```

DetailsFragment.class

```
public class DetailsFragment extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
    private int detailId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle icicle)
    {    
        super.onActivityCreated(icicle);
    }

    public static DetailsFragment newInstance(int id) {

        DetailsFragment lf = new DetailsFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("id", id);
        lf.setArguments(bundle);
        return lf;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listing, container, false);
        detailId = getArguments().getInt("id");
        DisplayItems();

        return view;
    }

    private void DisplayItems()
    {
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).getBoolean("value", false);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be setting variables and calling methods that have to do with initialization from the activity like that.`Id` should be set using `setArguments(...)` and using a static `newInstance(...)` method to instantiate your fragment.  You should call `displayItems()` in `onCreateView(...)` inside your Fragment, not from the attached Activity.

See the official Android guide on Fragments for more information.  You definitely should give the whole thing a read.  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my OP.  I seems to be working a little better.